# Algorithm and Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What does it mean when we say that an algorithm X is asymptotically more efficient than Y?

we consider the growth of the algorithm in terms of input size. I am not getting the concept properly.

Comment: This article might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Imagine you have two phonebooks: One is sorted normally, but for whatever reason it takes a full minute to open it to a new page. Another can be opened normally, but is unsorted. If the phonebooks are both very short, looking someone up in the latter might be faster, but if they're long, the first will be faster. "asymptotically" means "as something tends towards infinity", in this case, the length of the phone book. So we say the sorted phone book is asymptotically more efficient, which is distinct from it being faster at any particular size.

Comment: More generally, though, this is something on which a ton of very talented people have written a ton of learning material. You'll be better off googling and reading their planned and reviewed introductions, rather than getting off-the-cuff answers here. StackOverflow is a good resource for specific questions you either can't search for or think might be unique to you - it's a bad place for getting introduced to a common concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The growth of algorithm appears when we use containers such as Array,stack,queue and other data structures.If an array size is taken from the user then it will take O(N)(big-oh of N size) in terms of space complexity.

In terms of Time complexity, if there is any loop in the program running for n number of time then it will take O(N)(big-oh of N) time complexity.

These are the two main attributes while judging the growth of any algorithm.